# CORS issue with s3 when trying to download images

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After weeks of trying to find a solution, I'm giving up. Everything I tried didn't work so far

I uploaded images to an s3 bucket and defined them as public.

When my users try to download them through a JavaScript function on my front-end (using a:href), I get an error because of CORS policies. I tried to use canvas, but I also have a CORS error.

The images are properly displayed in the <img> tags tho, and when users right-click > save image, it works fine, the issue is when trying to download them automatically.

```
I tried this CORS policy:

[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]
```

and probably 5 others, but it did not changed anything.

**The result I'm trying to achieve:**

1. Upload image on s3 on my end
2. Users can click on a button to download it directly on the front end

Any help would be super useful

Comment: CORS happens when you try to access an API from another domain.
and i think you need to be more specific about your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you resolve this problem? Can you share it? badly needed

Answer (score 0):

try allowing the `HEAD` method also. It should work.